# Как превратить short массив с кодами символов в строку?

Tags: java, строки

Заранее извиняюсь, неправильно комментарий поставил в коде. Я ввожу строку,далее перевожу ее массив байтов.Затем этот массив байтов присваиваю массиву short,потому что byte только от -127 до 128, а ASCII таблица больше.Затем я в зависимости от введенного пароля,шифрую массив(просто сдвигаю элемент либо вправо либо влево,либо инверсия).На выходе у меня выходит short массив с зашифрованным кодом символом из строки которую мы вводили.Так вот я хочу перевести этот новый код символом в строку,чтобы вышла новая зашифрованная строка.Там после After Crypt: стоит комментарий, массив с зашифрованными символами называется crypting,перепробовал уже кучу разных методом никак не могу превратить все это в строку из символов, а не из кодов.

```
package supreme; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    static   byte[] tempCrypt;
    static  short [] crypting;
    static  char [] password;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        menu();
    }
    //[S@7225790e
    public static  void menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.print("1.Crypt\n2.Uncrypt\n3.Exit\nPlease make your choice: ");
        switch(choice = in.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your string which will be crypted: ");
                String line = in.next() + in.nextLine();
                tempCrypt = line.getBytes();
                crypting = new short[tempCrypt.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < tempCrypt.length; i++ ) {
                    crypting[i] = tempCrypt[i];
                }
                System.out.println("Please enter your password(it can be any number): ");
                int tempPassw = in.nextInt();
                String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(tempPassw);
                System.out.print("Password is: ");
                System.out.println(temp);
                password = temp.toCharArray();
                for (int i =  0; i < crypting.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(crypting[i]);
                }

//                ____CRYPTING
                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < crypting.length; i++) {
//                    System.out.println("Length is:" + crypting.length);
//                    System.out.println("Counter is:" + counter);
                    if(counter == crypting.length || counter > crypting.length) counter = 0;

                    if((password[counter] == '1') && (password[counter+1] == '0')) {
                        crypting[i] = (short)(crypting[i] << 1);
//                        System.out.println(crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println("<<");
                    }
                    if(password[counter] == '0' && password[counter+1] == '1') {
                        crypting[i] = (short)(crypting[i] >> 1);
//                        System.out.println(crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println(">>");
                    }
                    if(password[counter] == '1' && password[counter+1] == '1') {
                        crypting[i] = (short)(~crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println(crypting[i]);
//                        System.out.println("~");
                    }
                    counter+=2;
                }
                System.out.println("After crypt:");
//                for( int i = 0; i <crypting.length; i ++ ) {
//                    System.out.println("Element " + i +" is: " +  crypting[i]);
//                }
                 ________________________________________________________
                /*!!!!Здесь массив с зашифрованными кодами символов, его 
                 нужно как то превратить в строку.*/
                _________________________________________________________
                System.out.println("Exit program?(y/n)");
                String answer = in.next();
                if(answer.equals("y")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    menu();
                }


            }
            case 2:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Please, choose one of the possible variants:");
                menu();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Добавьте все эти уточнения в тело вопроса (кнопка "править"), а комментарии удалите

Comment: Немного смущает, что для передачи одинакового объема информации при шифровании нужно использовать тип в два раза более емкий, чем исходный. Может быть в уже в преобразовании byte -> short есть какие то загвоздки?

Comment: Чем извиняться за неправильный комментарий в коде, лучше было его просто убрать или исправить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, несколько замечаний по структуре кода.

1) Очевидно, при любом выборе функции вам надо будет ввести входную строку и пароль, а потом уже, в зависимости от выбора пользователя, выполнить над ними ту или функцию. Тогда лучше вынести вывод подсказки и ввод данных за пределы `switch`, чтобы не повторять один код 10 раз:

```
    System.out.print("1.Crypt\n2.Uncrypt\n3.Exit\nPlease make your choice: ");
    int choice = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the data: ");
    String data = in.next() + in.nextLine();
    // И прочее что нужно, подобным образом  

    switch(choice) {
        case 1: doCase1(); // делаем одно   
                break;
        case 2: doCase2(); // делаем другое 
                break;
        // и так далее
    }
```

2) Никогда не надо помещать громоздкий код в оператор switch -- это тяжело читать, сопровождать и изменять. Выносите содержательную часть работы в отдельные методы:

```
    switch(choice) {
        case 1: result = encrypt(input, password);  break;
        case 2: result = decrypt(input, password);  break;
        // и так далее
    }
```

В таком варианте, если вам захочется изменить алгоритм, или использовать несколько разных классов, реализующих разные алгоритмы в разных обстоятельствах, или добавить новые алгоритмы, не ломая рабочий код -- сделать это будет намного проще.

Теперь собственно по вашему коду (и вашему вопросу).

Во первых, в коде есть ошибка:

```
 // в цикле шифрования  
 counter += 2; // это конец предыдущей итерации  

 if(counter == crypting.length || counter > crypting.length) counter = 0;
 // Можно было просто if (counter >= crypting.length) ! 
 // После этого counter < crypting.length, т. е. возможно counter == crypting.length - 1 

 if((password[counter] == '1') && (password[counter+1] == '0')) {
   // если counter == crypting.length - 1, то counter + 1 == crypting.length, 
   // выход за пределы массива (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) !!!
```

Во вторых, мне непонятна ваша логика -- зачем вам преобразовывать строку в байты, а потом байты в `short`? Массив символов (`char[]`), который "родной" для `String`, также позволяет делать арифметические и побитовые операции над своими элементами -- и мудрить не надо с преобразованиями. Вы пишете "ASCII таблица больше" -- но 1) это не так, в ASCII ровно те же 256 символов (она на байты и была рассчитана); 2) В общем случае, упрощенно говоря, `Java` использует `unicode` и символ кодируется не одним байтом -- если вы думаете, что одна буква у вас будет всегда превращаться в один байт, то это не так; 3) Ели всё же хочется преобразовать, то почему в `short[]`, а не в `int[]`? Экономия памяти за счет меньшего размера `short` вряд ли может сыграть роль в реальной жизни, а сделать строку из `int[]` (как и из `char[]`) совсем не проблема.

В третьих, в алгоритме шифрования вы используете сдвиги `>>` и `<<`. Это операции необратимые -- крайний бит выдвигается и теряется, вы не сможете расшифровать то, что зашифровали.

Учитывая всё это, я бы сделал то, что вы пытались сделать, как-то вот так:

```
// Шифрует строку и возвращает результат 
private static String encrypt(String line, int pwd) { 
    char[] chars = line.toCharArray();            // символы строки
    String encrKey = Integer.toBinaryString(pwd); // перекодированный ключ 
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        String keyPart = new StringBuilder().     // фрагмент ключа из смежных символов в виде строки 
                append(encrKey.charAt(i % encrKey.length())).       // i % encrKey.length() не выходит за границы массива 
                append(encrKey.charAt((i + 1) % encrKey.length())). // после перебора символов начинает с начала ключа 
                toString();
        switch (keyPart) {
            case "10": chars[i] = (char)Integer.rotateLeft((int)chars[i], 1); break; // циклический сдвиг (обратимый) 
            case "01": chars[i] = (char)Integer.rotateRight((int)chars[i], 1); break; 
            case "11": chars[i] = (char)~chars[i]; break; 
    }
    }
    return new String(chars); // Зашифрованная строка
}

public static  void menu() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // .useDelimiter("\\s+");

    System.out.print("1.Crypt\n2.Uncrypt\n3.Exit\nPlease make your choice: ");
    int choice = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter your string which will be crypted: ");
    String line = in.next() + in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your password(it can be any number): ");
    int pwd = in.nextInt();

    switch(choice) {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Input:     " + line);   // Если надо их выводить 
            String encrypted = encrypt(line, pwd);      // Результат шифрования 
            System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
            break; 
        case 2:  
            // Следующая операция
```